# Table Primary key index size vary with data type

Tags: sql-server-2008, indexing

I have created two table in sql 2008 r2 and and table statistics as below given screen.
when I am re-build indexing of table, size of index goes vary high for both table where most of the column and data type is same.[image: Table Statistics]

[image: Table Detail][image]

Can you please suggest me on this.

I have already checked RCSI of database and index offline and online.
RCSI is disable and index is offline.

Answer (score 0):

Well different data type need different size to be storage.

When you create the index you need save the information regarding the index field for each row. So you need less bytes to store one `unique indentifer`(4/8 bytes) than store one string (variable length.

More **[INFO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190620.aspx)**

> Num_Key_Cols = total number of key columns (fixed-length and variable-length)
>   Fixed_Key_Size = total byte size of all fixed-length key columns
>   Num_Variable_Key_Cols = number of variable-length key columns
>   Max_Var_Key_Size = maximum byte size of all variable-length key columns

Comment: I am looking for primary index.

Comment: and why you think that is different?